# How is fluid grid system implemented, what's the principle behind it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, grid-system

I just started learning css, bootstrap is most popular css RWD framework. I'm just curious how the fluid grid system is implemented ??

And I accidently learned the wip w3c css standard [multi-column layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-multicol-20110412/). Is it the same concept as grid system? Does it make all the grid system library out there outdated when it's finalized and fully implemented by all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn CSS I would learn CSS first, I wouldn't touch bootstrap. Bootstrap is for "ease of use" not for learning css. You won't learn much with boostrap, just how to find which bootstrap class to use in what case.

I'm not sure if I understand the question in the same way as you mean it. But the difference between container and container-fluid is that container has 4 resolution "marks" at which point it will switch to that particular mode (mobiles, tablets, desktops, large desktops) and the width of the container stays the same until the width of the screen comes to the next mark. Container-fluid still has the same marks for the "modes" but the width of the container spreads with the width of the screen.

And as for your last question, I wouldn't be worried about that.